Does the lactic acid in yogurt hurt the enamel of teeth?
I got seemingly contradicting messages concerning the impact of lactic acid from yogurt on teeth
From this article

Balances PH levels in the mouth – The types of bacteria that can cause dental cavities and tooth decay tend to thrive in highly acidic environments. Yogurt is able to help balance the PH levels in the mouth, lowering the acidity and ridding the mouth of germs and bacteria.

But from this article, it says:

We’ve always been told that sugar causes cavities, but it’s really lactic acid that does the damage. A bacterium in our mouths called Streptococcus mutans converts sugar to lactic acid, which eats tooth enamel.

I am inclined to believe the second statement, because intuitively lactic acid is an acid and should lower the pH level in mouth. But I am far from being an expert and which someone could clarify this for me. Maybe yogurt itself doesn't contain enough lactic acid to threat teeth?

Lactic acid and other acids produced by anaerobic bacteria (e.g. streptococcus mutans, Lactobacillus sps) These bacteria grow optimally on fermentable sugars by utilizing anaerobic glycolysis. Lactic acid can erode tooth enamel and dentin, and dissolve hydroxyapatite matrix of teeth but the risk is relatively low due to the mild concentration of acid, the presence of calcium and phosphates that can neutralize and remineralize teeth, and the close pH level to the natural mouth pH. However, good oral hygiene practices, such as rinsing with water, regular brushing with fluoride toothpaste are still essential to maintain healthy teeth and minimize any potential enamel erosion.

Good answer, or at least it would be if you provided a supporting reference or two. That's probably why the downvote. Answers here are required to provide supporting references to claims of fact. No, you don't have to make it a thesis, but a link or two supporting your main points would be appreciated.
